# Prevent commiting files to SVN with warnings using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subclipse

I have a big Java project with thousands of compilation warnings. I would like to find a way to prevent developers commiting files with warnings, so gradually all warnings would disappear. If I commit a file with compilation error Eclipse displays an error message, but I couldnt find any way to do the same with warnings. The closest thing I found was The Commit warning checker http://commitwarncheck.sourceforge.net/ but that is not really integrated into the commit process, it just provides a view. Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see 2 options.  First, at least with [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/), there's an Eclipse preference for this:  Window / Preferences / Team / SVN / "Commit resources with warnings".  There's one for "errors" as well.  Both can be set to "Yes", "No", or "Prompt".  However, this will require you to make sure that your entire team keeps these options set as you'd expect - as well as making sure that they have all of the other Eclipse preferences set to generate the same errors / warnings.

Using Subclipse 1.6.18:

[image]

Another option is to make use of [SVN commit hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks), essentially the beginnings of a Continuous Integration (CI) process.  You could actually check for a limited set of things, and allow/deny the commit at that time, but I'd start worrying about commit performance.  A better option might be a true CI process that runs a build (either scheduled, or potentially even per-commit) - and emails or otherwise alerts the developer if an issue is detected.

The complication with this later option is repeating the Eclipse build - including detection of all Eclipse-configured errors and warnings - in a scripted manner.  (If anyone finds a great way of doing this, please let me know!  Eclipse provides a scriptable option for using its code formatter, but I've not seen a similar option for checking for errors / warnings using the checks provided by Eclipse.)

Otherwise, you'll probably be better off starting to migrate over to tools such as [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) and [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) that work equally well both inside and outside of Eclipse.  (However, relating back to my own interest above, I've not found any combination of a few tools - including these - that can at least match the same checks that Eclipse provides.)  Combine this with [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) / [m2e](http://eclipse.org/m2e/), providing a common build configuration / process that can be shared by both Eclipse and your CI system, and you should be in good shape.

Comment: We have both CI and Sonar (checkstyle+PMD) but to be honest noone really cares about the notifications. We are all under time pressure and never have the time to read those emails :) I have the latest version of subclipse but dont have the option you mention. Either I am totally blind or using a different version. Which one do you have? Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: @PeterSzanto - your team needs to care about the notifications.  Once they start being taken seriously, your development process will improve, and your time pressure should decrease.  In terms of the Subclipse options mentioned, I've added a screenshot.

Comment: I looked at least 10 times that screen before asking here, but I always focused on the check boxes, not the radio buttons:) Thanks for the screenshot!