# Prompt before committing files with compiler warnings, using Subversive team provider

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subversive

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618678/prevent-commiting-files-to-svn-with-warnings-using-eclipse), I'd like to have a warning prompt before I am allowed to commit files into Subversion which contain compiler warnings.

Unlike the linked question, I'm using the standard [Subversive team provider](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/). Any suggestions? I don't see anything obvious in the preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've concluded there is no way to do this with Subversive and have raised an enhancement request about it:

[**Bug 263442 -** Add a pre-commit check for files with errors and warnings](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=442671)